# Reordering grid layout into 2 columns

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have the following div layout for mobile:
[image: Mobile View]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/000/fff&text=1" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x800/111/fff&text=2" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/222/fff&text=3" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/333/fff&text=4" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/444/fff&text=5" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/555/fff&text=6" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/666/fff&text=7" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x800/777/fff&text=8" alt="" class="w-100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

When I hit the medium breakpoint I would like to achieve the following layout:

[image: Desktop View]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is using disable flex on md using `d-md-block` and float utilities...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-md-block">
        <div class="col-md-4 float-right">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/000/fff&text=1" alt="1" class="w-100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 float-left">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x800/111/fff&text=2" alt="2" class="w-100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 float-right">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/222/fff&text=3" alt="3" class="w-100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 float-right">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/333/fff&text=4" alt="4" class="w-100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 float-right">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/444/fff&text=5" alt="5" class="w-100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 float-right">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/555/fff&text=6" alt="6" class="w-100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 float-right">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/666/fff&text=7" alt="7" class="w-100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 float-left">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x800/777/fff&text=8" alt="8" class="w-100" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/PnxQnq14Vn

Comment: Thanks @Zim, I'm almost there, I've altered the layout slightly but now I'm getting 8 and 7 top aligned.  I'd like to have 8 straight underneath 2 - see [https://www.codeply.com/p/JUG92r1Nt5](https://www.codeply.com/p/JUG92r1Nt5) - All sections will have dynamically generated content to they will vary in height

Comment: Yeah that's not going to work. Floats are very specific to the heights/widths

Comment: No worries, I'll just setup as is with the dynamic content and see how best I can arrange them